# Can't deploy to Elasticbeanstalk: "ebcli.lib.s3 : No data left, closing"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an environment on Elasticbeanstalk using the eb CLI.
I have a PHP application that I'm deploying using a zip of the code.  I'm trying to use the EB CLI to do most things.
I have tried to deploy to it, but I keep getting the error:

`...ebcli.lib.s3 : No data left, closing...`
I've done various debugging steps but from what I understand I've run out of hard disk space on the EBS volume which is mounted on the EC2 instance that is created by Elasticbeanstalk. Anyone see this error before?
Is there a way to assign a larger EBS volume to Elasticbeanstalk when running `eb create` to create the environment?

This is what I get when I run `eb deploy testing --debug`:
See below:

````
2019-10-21 16:23:07,395 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2019-10-21 16:23:07,395 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '00--ommitted', 'HostId': 'omitted
ommitted', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'date': 'Mon, 21 Oct 2019 14:21:36 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'ETag': '"00--ommitted"'}
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2019-10-21 16:23:07,396 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.s3 : No data left, closing
2019-10-21 16:23:07,401 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (s3, complete_multipart_upload) to region: us-east-1 with args:{'Bucket'```

Thanks for your help.
````

Comment: That doesn't look like an error, more its just finished uploading the file and that there is nothing left to upload so the connection can be closed.

Comment: Thanks, I think my issue with creating new environments might have to do with the current Route53 outage.